# Artin 2.10.3 help understanding why $AN=NA=A$ implies $N$ is normal

Tags: group-theory

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/202064/441764

I understand how to show that $N$ is a subgroup.  I'm looking at this answer which claims that $AN = NA = A$ means that $N$ is normal. This isn't obvious to me.  How do you use this fact to show that $N$ is normal?  If I could show that $AN = aN$ then the left and right cosets would be equal.  It seems that $AN = NA = A$ does not imply $an = na$ for any $a \in A$ and $n \in N$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution.  Let $ a \in A $ and let $B$ be the partition containing $a^{-1}$.

$$ AN = NA = A $$
$$ ANB = AB $$

AB will contain the element 1.  It will be the subset of some partition.  The only partition containing 1 is N.  So $ AB \subset N $

$$ ANB \subset N $$

You can choose any arbitrary element $ a \in G $ from some partition $ A \in P $.  So I think that will show $ gng^{-1} \in N \forall g \in G $

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have some $ n \in N$ and $a \in A$. Since $NA=A$ it follows that $na \in A$. Let $n^{-1}$ be the inverse of $n$ meaning $n^{-1} \in N$. Since $n^{-1}$ is in $N$ and $na \in A$ it follows that $na n^{-1} \in AN$. Therefore $nan^{-1} \in A$. Since we've choosen $n$ and $a$ arbitrarily this means that $nan^{-1} \in A$ for all $a \in A $ and $n \in N$. Therefore $A \lhd N $. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Not quite, what I'm trying to show is that N is a normal subgroup of G.  Under your approach I'd need to show that $ gng^-1 \in N $ since the $A$ in the formula above can be any set in the partition, to show that $ ana^-1 \in N $ would suffice to show $ N \triangleleft A $.

Answer (score 0):

The group $G$ is given a partition $P$ with the condition that two elements of the partition is some other element of the partition, i.e. a binary operation on the partitions that is closed. We are also told that the partition $N$ has the element $1$.

Next, define a set map $\psi$ from $G$ to $P$ as $x \mapsto P_x$, where $P_x$ is the partition that contains $x$.

Now, equip $P$ with a group operation in the obvious fashion. Notice, that N is the identity element or as you write $AN = NA = A$.

Then the set map $\psi$ is a homomorphism and the partition $N$ is its kernel.