# Let $P$ be a partition of a group with $AB \subseteq C$. Why is $1 \in P_n$? $P_n$ is the equivalence class of $n \in N$ and $1 \in N=P_1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, set-partition, quotient-group

> Let P be a partition of a group G with the property that for any pair of elements A, B of the partition, the product set AB is contained entirely within another element C of the partition. Let N be the element of P that contains 1. Prove that N is a normal subgroup of G and that P is the set of its cosets.

This exercise was asked about in the following questions: [partition of a group to have normal subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388268/partition-of-a-group-to-have-normal-subgroup) [partition of a group and cosets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458212/partition-of-a-group-and-cosets) [Proving a partition is set of cosets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201969/proving-a-partition-is-set-of-cosets?rq=1) [Artin 2.10.3 help understanding why $AN=NA=A$ implies $N$ is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258298/artin-2-10-3-help-understanding-why-an-na-a-implies-n-is-normal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My question is about Brian Bi's proof linked [here](http://brianbi.ca/artin/2.12), where it is claimed that $1 \in P_n$.

The following is a screenshot of the proof (Kiefer Sutherland's voice):

[image]

Please explain the $1 \in P_n$. This is the only part I don't understand.

Comment: $P_n$ is the partition to which $n$ belongs, i.e., $N$. But we already know that $1\in N$

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe $N=P_n=P_1$? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n$ belongs to some element $P_n$ of the partition $P$.

$n$ belongs to $N$.

We are given that $N$ is not just any subset of $G$: $N$ is also an element of $P$.

$\therefore, N \cap P_n \ne \emptyset \implies N = P_n$

$1 \in P_1 = N \implies \therefore, 1 \in P_n$.